# VB.Net Multiple background workers - Only last task completes

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work. If I step through the code in debugger it all works great.

My problem is if I just run it, only the last task responds. I'm guessing I am overwriting the background working or something. I am sure I am doing a few things wrong but my code is now messy as I tried many way while searching. I know of the threadpool and .Net 4.0 tasks but having a hard time getting to do what I need.

Basicly I am writing a program (trying more likely) that takes a list of computers and pings then, then checks their uptime and reports back.

This works fine in the UI thread (Obviously that locks up my screen). I can have the background worker just do this, but then it does each computer 1 by one, and while the screen is responsive it still takes a long time.

So my answer was to have a for loop for each server launching a new background worker thread. My solution does not work.

I have seen other threads that I could do it, but I need to use with events to call code to update to UI when each is done.

What is the most simple way to do this?

Here is my code. Most is just copy paste + modify till I get it working right.

So In the main class I have the testworker.

(I tried using Testworker() but it said I could not do that WithEvents)

When I click the button the list loads.

```
Private WithEvents TestWorker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.IsEnabled = False

    Dim indexMax As Integer
                    indexMax = DataGridStatus.Items.Count
    For index = 1 To (indexMax)
        Dim Temp As ServerInfo = DataGridStatus.Items(index - 1)
        Temp.Index = index - 1
        Call_Thread(Temp)
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub Call_Thread(ByVal server As ServerInfo)
    Dim localserver As ServerInfo = server

    TestWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    TestWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    TestWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    TestWorker.RunWorkerAsync(localserver)

End Sub

Private Sub TestWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles TestWorker.DoWork

    Dim iparray As IPHostEntry
    Dim ip() As IPAddress

    Dim Server As ServerInfo
    Server = e.Argument
    Try
        'Get IP Address first
        iparray = Dns.GetHostEntry(Server.ServerName)
        ip = iparray.AddressList
        Server.IPAddress = ip(0).ToString

        'Try Pinging
        Server.PingResult = PingHost(Server.ServerName)
        If Server.PingResult = "Success" Then

            'If ping success, get uptime
            Server.UpTime = GetUptime(Server.ServerName)
        Else
            Server.PingResult = "Failed"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Server.PingResult = "Error"
    End Try

    TestWorker.ReportProgress(0, Server)
    Thread.Sleep(1000)

End Sub


Private Sub TestWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles TestWorker.ProgressChanged

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim serverchange As ServerInfo = DirectCast(e.UserState, ServerInfo)

    index = DataGridStatus.Items.IndexOf(serverchange)
    ' index = serverchange.Index
    DataGridStatus.Items.Item(index) = serverchange

    ' ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    DataGridStatus.Items.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using Ping.SendAsync()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only getting the last result because you are blowing away your `BackgroundWorker` each time you call `TestWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`. Since the processing is being done asynchronously, this line is being called multiple times within your `for` loop before the previous work has finished.

Something like the following might work. (Sorry, my VB is rusty; there are probably more efficient ways of expressing this.)

```
Delegate Function PingDelegate(ByVal server As String) As String

Private _completedCount As Int32
Private ReadOnly _lockObject As New System.Object
Dim _rnd As New Random
Private _servers As List(Of String)

Private Sub GoButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoButton.Click
    _servers = New List(Of System.String)(New String() {"adam", "betty", "clyde", "danny", "evan", "fred", "gertrude", "hank", "ice-t", "joshua"})
    _completedCount = 0
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    GoButton.Enabled = False
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(_servers)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim servers As List(Of System.String) = DirectCast(e.Argument, List(Of System.String))
    Dim waitHandles As New List(Of WaitHandle)

    For Each server As System.String In servers
        ' Get a delegate for the ping operation. .Net will let you call it asynchronously
        Dim d As New PingDelegate(AddressOf Ping)

        ' Start the ping operation async. When the ping is complete, it will automatically call PingIsDone
        Dim ar As IAsyncResult = d.BeginInvoke(server, AddressOf PingIsDone, d)

        ' Add the IAsyncResult for this invocation to our collection.
        waitHandles.Add(ar.AsyncWaitHandle)
    Next

    ' Wait until everything is done. This will not block the UI thread because it is happening
    ' in the background. You could also use the overload that takes a timeout value and
    ' check to see if the user has requested cancellation, for example. Once all operations
    ' are complete, this method will exit scope and the BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted 
    ' will be called.
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray())
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1}% done)", e.UserState, e.ProgressPercentage))
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    GoButton.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Function Ping(ByVal server As System.String) As System.String
    ' Simulate a ping with random result and duration
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(_rnd.Next(1000, 4000))
    Dim result As Int32 = _rnd.Next(0, 2)
    If result = 0 Then
        Return server & " is ok"
    Else
        Return server & " is down"
    End If
End Function

Private Sub PingIsDone(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    ' This method is called everytime a ping operation completes. Note that the order in which
    ' this method fires is completely independant of the order of the servers. The first server
    ' to respond calls this method first, etc. This keeps optimal performance.
    Dim d As PingDelegate = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, PingDelegate)

    ' Complete the operation and get the result.
    Dim pingResult As String = d.EndInvoke(ar)

    ' To be safe, we put a lock around this so that _completedCount gets incremented atomically
    ' with the progress report. This may or may not be necessary in your application.
    SyncLock (_lockObject)
        _completedCount = _completedCount + 1
        Dim percent As Int32 = _completedCount * 100 / _servers.Count
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percent, pingResult)
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Comment: Dave, I figured it was something like that. I saw you could declare the background worker as Testworker() but it doesn't let me do it with "WithEvents" which is what I need. Will await your responce. Hopefully you can show me the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Jasin: You *don't* need `WithEvents` to handle your worker's events. In VB the way to do this dynamically is by using `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Wow. Ok at first I thought you were just using 1 background worker. But you are using the background worker to then call threads to the ping. Will take me a bit to understand it but that is helpful and works great. Just need to include it in my code.
Thank you very much

Comment: Right. In a sense, this makes the `BackgroundWorker` irrelevant, but it does provide the convenience of automatically knowing how to report things back to the UI thread so you don't have to manually invoke them over there. But the heavy lifting is done using the Asynchronous Programming Model.

Comment: Just saw you added comments. Thanks again, Answered my other questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I posted this answer focusing on exactly what you were trying to do from a technical standpoint (use many background workers) without really putting much thought into whether or not this was a good way to accomplish your *real* objective. In fact, I think you could achieve what you're going for much more easily with a single `BackgroundWorker` and something like a [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) loop in its `DoWork` event handler (this takes care of a lot of the nitty gritty work in, e.g., [Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808525/vb-net-multiple-background-workers-only-last-task-completes/4808943#4808943) solution).

---

When you declare `WithEvents TestWorker As BackgroundWorker` in VB it wraps it up something like this (not exactly—this is just to illustrate the idea):

```
Private _TestWorker As BackgroundWorker
Private Property TestWorker As BackgroundWorker
    Get
        Return _TestWorker
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BackgroundWorker)
        ' This is all probably handled in a more thread-safe way, mind you. '

        Dim prevWorker As BackgroundWorker = _TestWorker
        If prevWorker IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler prevWorker.DoWork, AddressOf TestWorker_DoWork
            ' etc. '
        End If

        If value IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler value.DoWork, AddressOf TestWorker_DoWork
            ' etc. '
        End If
        _TestWorker = value
    End Set
End Property
```

When you realize this, it becomes clear that by *setting* `TestWorker` to a **new** `BackgroundWorker` on every call to `Call_Thread`, you are removing any attached handlers from the object previously referenced by the field.

The most obvious fix would simply be to create a new **local** `BackgroundWorker` object in each call to `Call_Thread`, attach the handlers there (using `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`), and then just let it do its thing:

```
Private Sub Call_Thread(ByVal server As ServerInfo)
    Dim localserver As ServerInfo = server

    ' Use a local variable for the new worker. '
    ' This takes the place of the Private WithEvents field. '
    Dim worker As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    ' Set it up. '
    With worker
        .WorkerReportsProgress = True
        .WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    End With

    ' Attach the handlers. '
    AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf TestWorker_DoWork
    AddHandler worker.ProgressChanged, AdressOf TestWorker_ProgressChanged

    ' Do the work. '
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(localserver)
End Sub
```

Creating the worker right there in the method should be fine as long as you do so from the UI thread, since `BackgroundWorker` automatically attaches to the current `SynchronizationContext` in its constructor (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Dan, Thanks I was looking at AddHandler events but I couldn't find a way to pass and recieve values.

Comment: @Jasin: `AddHandler` just does that: adds the handler. You would still call `RunWorkerAsync` (as you are in the code in your question) to raise the event and would pass the value the very same way.

Comment: Dan So you mean when I RunWorkerAsync( I can include the values here that the function would normally be expecting {in my case a custom class}) Thank you I didn't understand that at first.

Comment: @Jasin: See my edit. Hopefully that helps to illustrate what I mean?

Comment: Yes Sir, Thank you Very Much. I'd give you points but have no rep to do anything.

Comment: @Jasin: Haha, no worries. I appreciate the sentiment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `TestWorker_DoWork` and `TestWorker_ProgressChanged` to the `DoWork` and `ProgressChanged` events within `Call_Thread`. I haven't yet examined the rest of the code, but that is why it isn't doing anything now.

```
TestWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
TestWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
TestWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
AddHandler TestWorker.DoWork, AddressOf TestWorker_DoWork
AddHandler TestWorker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf TestWorker_ProgressChanged
TestWorker.RunWorkerAsync(localserver)
```

Comment: Adam, Thanks I tried that but I get an error on the two that say the two are events and cannot be raised directly. The last computer on the list does display correctly.

Comment: Adam, in VB the syntax to add/remove handlers is with `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` as opposed to the `+=` operator C# uses (I think this is why @Jasin is confused by your code).

Comment: @Jasin: Sorry about that; while I copied your VB.NET code, for some reason I wrote the event attaching code in C#. This should work for you now. @Dan: Duh, thanks for that! Not sure what I was thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use only 1 backgroundworker and use it like this:

- Assemble all the work that needs to be done: in your case a list of ServerInfo
- Do the work in the background: ping all the servers and keep the result
- Report progress: for example after each server pinged
- Put results back in DoWorkEventArgs.Result
- Display the results back in your UI.

Comment: Zippy, Thanks I may have to resort to that. I would like to use multiple threads because we plan to ping and get info from 100 or so servers at a time so it would be nice to be able to ping multiple at the same time to speed the process up.